# 16-bit MASM implement this algorithm into code (confusion) ASCII to decimal

Tags: assembly, decimal, ascii, masm

I need to take user input of ASCII characters, and then convert that to decimal characters.
Here is the algorithm I thought up for this but not sure how to show it in code. Ideas? It will only take 0-9 characters and will validate for this. I haven't written anything to do with ASCII and not sure what syntax to use. Here is my pseudo-code algorithm

```
Give it a counter variable: 
counter = 0
getCharacters( next character ) ; next ASCII character from left
while ( next character != CR(enter key)
    validate next character
    digit = next character - 30hex 
    counter = (counter * 10) + digit
end loop
return counter in AX
```

How would I put that into direct masm? I am a noobie.

Comment: "How do I implement this algorithm in assembly?" is a poor question. Start writing the assembly code, and if there's a particular part that you can't figure out from the documentation available; as a question about that.

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar for storing the input number in `AX`. You can find the procedure [here](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6356116#file-indec-asm) on gist.github.com

```asm
INDEC PROC
    PUSH BX
    PUSH DX
    XOR BX, BX
    XOR AX, AX
  READ:
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21H
    CMP AL, CR
  JE END_READ
    CMP AL, LF
  JE END_READ
    CMP AL, '0'
  JNGE NON_INTEGER
    CMP AL, '9'
  JNLE NON_INTEGER
  MY_LOOP:
    AND AX, 000FH
    PUSH AX
    MOV AX, 10
    MUL BX
    POP BX
    ADD BX, AX
  JMP READ
  END_READ:
    MOV AX, BX
    POP DX
    POP BX
   RET
  NON_INTEGER:
    LEA DX, NON_NUM      ;; The NON_NUM is a `$` terminated string to display error
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H
  JMP READ
INDEC ENDP
```